# Twitter browser notifications are unsupported

Tags: firefox, twitter, push-notification, archlinux, libnotify

I can't activate Twitter web notifications on Firefox as you can see on the screenshot below

[Twitter settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFLg.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the solution !

I just had forgotten to check the "Renember me" box before logging in. When I do that, the web notifications become available on all browsers.